How to extract the ids of options array when parsing a json file
I want to parse JSONs files, which look like the data file in the function below.
I can extract all the data I need for my report from data except the options array ids
so in the question Sector of the json file data, it has the options array
"options": {
      "62f92fab79ac81d933765bd0bbc4a1f5ea26cb3a088bcb4e6e": {
        "index": 0,
        "value": "Bob",
        "label": "Bob",
        "count": 1
      },
      "2fe91aa3567c0d04c521dcd2fc7e40d7622bb8c3f594d503da": {
        "index": 1,
        "value": "Student",
        "label": "Student",
        "count": 1
      },
      "c59ea1159f33b91a7f6edc6925be5e373fc543e4": {
        "index": 5,
        "value": "AAA",
        "label": "AAA"
      }
    }

I need to extract
62f92fab79ac81d933765bd0bbc4a1f5ea26cb3a088bcb4e6e
2fe91aa3567c0d04c521dcd2fc7e40d7622bb8c3f594d503da
c59ea1159f33b91a7f6edc6925be5e373fc543e4

and added it to my output
The output I have
c3c6f410f58e5836431b473ebcf134756232d04f2bf35edff8
Sector
Bob
Student
AAA

f794c6a52e793ee6f5c42cd5df6b4435236e3495e951709485
Question AAA

The output I need
c3c6f410f58e5836431b473ebcf134756232d04f2bf35edff8
Sector
62f92fab79ac81d933765bd0bbc4a1f5ea26cb3a088bcb4e6e
Bob
2fe91aa3567c0d04c521dcd2fc7e40d7622bb8c3f594d503da
Student
c59ea1159f33b91a7f6edc6925be5e373fc543e4
AAA

f794c6a52e793ee6f5c42cd5df6b4435236e3495e951709485
Question AAA

Thanks
function ParseJSON() {
  let data = [
    {
    "id": "c3c6f410f58e5836431b473ebcf134756232d04f2bf35edff8",
    "component": "checkbox",
    "customFields": [

    ],
    "index": 0,
    "label": "Sector",
    "options": {
      "62f92fab79ac81d933765bd0bbc4a1f5ea26cb3a088bcb4e6e": {
        "index": 0,
        "value": "Bob",
        "label": "Bob",
        "count": 1
      },
      "2fe91aa3567c0d04c521dcd2fc7e40d7622bb8c3f594d503da": {
        "index": 1,
        "value": "Student",
        "label": "Student",
        "count": 1
      },
      "c59ea1159f33b91a7f6edc6925be5e373fc543e4": {
        "index": 5,
        "value": "AAA",
        "label": "AAA"
      }
    },
    "required": false,
    "validation": "/.*/",
    "imported": false
  },
  {
    "id": "f794c6a52e793ee6f5c42cd5df6b4435236e3495e951709485",
    "component": "textInput",
    "customFields": [

    ],
    "index": 1,
    "label": "Question AAA",
    "options": {
    },
    "required": false,
    "validation": "/.*/",
    "imported": false
  }
 ];

  let result = "";
  data.forEach(({id, label, content, component, options}) => {
   if(component!=="htmlelement"){ 
    //filter out HTML componets
    content = label==="HTML" ? "":content;
    label= label==="HTML" ? "":label;

    content = content ? '\n' + content:"";
  
    component = component==='checkbox' ? "select_boxes":component;
    component = component==='textInput' ? "text input":component;
    component = component==='textArea' ? "text area":component;
    component = component==='url' ? "URL":component;
    component = component!=='htmlelement' ? component+'\n':"";
  
    if(id + component + label + content!==""){
      result += id + '\n' + label + content + '\n'+ parseOBJ(options);
      //result += console.log(component + label + content + '\n'+ parseOBJ(options));
      result += '\n'
    }

    result=result.replace(/[\r\n]{2,}/g, "\n\n");
   }
  });

  console.log(result)
}

function parseOBJ(obj) {
  let R =""
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    R += value.value + '\n';
  };
  
  return R
}


Does this answer your question? How can I access and process nested objects, arrays, or JSON?

Hey, jabaa thanks I did not come across this in my searching

TLDR; Object.keys

About your function parseOBJ, how about modifying R += value.value + '\n'; to R += key + "\n" + value.value + '\n';?

If your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer?

function myFunk() {
  let s = '{"options": { "62f92fab79ac81d933765bd0bbc4a1f5ea26cb3a088bcb4e6e": { "index": 0, "value": "Bob", "label": "Bob", "count": 1 }, "2fe91aa3567c0d04c521dcd2fc7e40d7622bb8c3f594d503da": { "index": 1, "value": "Student", "label": "Student","count": 1 },"c59ea1159f33b91a7f6edc6925be5e373fc543e4":{ "index": 5, "value": "AAA", "label": "AAA" } } }';
  let obj = JSON.parse(s);
  Logger.log(Object.keys(obj.options));
}

Execution log
9:48:07 PM  Notice  Execution started
9:48:08 PM  Info    [62f92fab79ac81d933765bd0bbc4a1f5ea26cb3a088bcb4e6e, 2fe91aa3567c0d04c521dcd2fc7e40d7622bb8c3f594d503da, c59ea1159f33b91a7f6edc6925be5e373fc543e4]
9:48:10 PM  Notice  Execution completed


We all have different ideas.  I would not take them  too seriously.  Our motivations are sometimes difficult to understand but almost anything other than a simple one line question accompanied with a [mcve] will stimulate a negative response.   Most are volunteers here.  Consider yourself fortunate if you can always avoid closure.  Answering questions is much easier than asking them. And the value for us is that if we are wrong we will find out pretty quickly.
